# Nested ng-repeat-start / ng-repeat-end

Tags: javascript, angularjs

`ng-repeat-start` / `ng-repeat-end` are used for looping through data without rendering parent element [[Portal to Docs]](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat). In my case, I want to display data in nested `ng-repeat-start` / `ng-repeat-end` blocks without extra elements.

I've tried to put two `ng-repeat-start` directives into the same element but it fails to display correctly. I somehow figured out a workaround as displayed below [[Portal to Demo]](http://jsbin.com/fedowijozabi/2/edit?html,output). Any better solution for case like this?

**data**

```
[{
    name: 'Chapter 1',
    sections: [{
        name: '1-1',
        words: 1024
    }, {
        name: '1-2',
        words: 512
    }]
}, {
    name: 'Chapter 2',
    sections: [{
        name: '2-1',
        words: 2048
    }, {
        name: '2-2',
        words: 256
    }]
}]
```

**html**

```
<tr class="tr-for" ng-repeat-start="chapter in main.book"></tr>
  <tr ng-repeat-start="section in chapter.sections" ng-repeat-end>
    <td>{{chapter.name}}</td>
    <td>{{section.name}}</td>
    <td>{{section.words}}</td>
  </tr>
<tr class="tr-end" ng-repeat-end></tr>
```

**css**

```
tr.tr-for,
tr.tr-end {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your internal ng-repeat should be the regular ngRepeat:

```
<tr class="tr-for" ng-repeat-start="chapter in main.book"></tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="section in chapter.sections">
        <td>{{chapter.name}}</td>
        <td>{{section.name}}</td>
        <td>{{section.words}}</td>
    </tr>
<tr class="tr-end" ng-repeat-end></tr>
```

**Update**

Try use the first ngRepeat inside of tbody tag:

```
<tbody ng-repeat="chapter in main.book">
  <tr ng-repeat-start="section in chapter.sections" ng-repeat-end>
    <td>{{chapter.name}}</td>
    <td>{{section.name}}</td>
    <td>{{section.words}}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: You are right. But is there any way not to use the css file to hide parent elements?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for arbitrary depth with ng-includes